# Sonarqube Documentation & Comments - widgets and for java language

Tags: java, sonarqube

Our Sonarqube Version – 5.6.7 
Java Plugin Version - sonar-java-plugin-4.15.0.12310

**Problem:**

We have configured (Documentation & Comments) widgets, But on sonarqube dashboard documentation information like (Public API & Pub. undoc. API) counts are not showing whereas comments counts are showing for java language. Does the feature removed from this java plugin version. Kindly confirm us.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using version 4.15 of the SonarJava code analyzer. Version 4.3 of that analyzer [dropped the relevant metrics](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1916). That's why your widget has no data.

---

**Edit**

I've inadvertently suggested that you regress your version of SonarJava. As a rule, you always want to move forward, never back. Each subsequent version of a code analyzer fixes bugs, improves existing rule implementations, and introduces new features.

You *will* need to upgrade your version of SonarQube eventually. When you do, you'll (re-)lose those metrics. Rather than installing an older version of the analyzer, you should give serious consideration to upgrading SonarQube. You're on 5.6, the previous LTS. At this writing the current version of SonarQube is 7.1 and the current LTS is 6.7.3.

Comment: Okay. Soon we will upgrade our Sonar version. Thank you.